# How to start and stop a video as well as a Timeline with Vuforia?

Tags: vuforia

I am very new to Unity / Vuforia scripting and really need help.
I have composed a whole Timeline in unity but cannot trigger an event ... there are still code errors ...
In the DefaultTrackableEventHandler script, I understand that you have to attach a piece of code that allows these events to be triggered but I haven't been able to do this for 48 hours. Help from the community would be very useful. please.
Here is the scenario:
When launching the application a video should appear. When the target is found, the video should stop to leave room for the Timeline which is triggered automatically, since the target has been found. If the user loses the target then the Timeleine will have to stop and the starting video will have to start again.
Someone could help me with this problem that has taken my head for 48 hours ...
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to write scripts that contains differents functions that manage all those points. One script that starts and stops your video (2 different functions), and a other that starts and stops your timeline. (Don't forget to hide the video when you stop it)

Once you have those scripts you can attach them to a object and then, use them in DefaultTrackableEventHandler. (You add you function to the right event by clicking the + button, dragging your object with the script and choosing the right function to use).

[Screenshot of DefaultTrackableEventHandler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnD0d.png)